# R 3.3.1 - Can I recover unsaved workspace/script?

Tags: r

I typed a lot of code and stupidly didn't save it when I was finished.  Is there anyway to recover this or am I out of luck?  I have read about .Rhistory but that does not work for me.  When I load workspace history it's just a bunch of nonsense I did months ago.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what your workflow is, but if you are using "raw" R, the answer is sadly no. The only place where any text might have been saved is the .Rhistory file.

This is why it is recommended to use an IDE which makes this workflow very natural. Combined with version control, there is probably no better way of ensuring the safety of the code. Of course, there is no system that will save the user from her or himself.